# Terraform with Azure

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-virtual-machine, vhd

How can i create a VM (diff SubscriptionID) using Customized Image (VHD) which is at different subscriptions storage account. Used this

```
storage_os_disk {
    name              = "${var.Servername}-os-disk"
    create_option     = "FromImage"
    caching           = "${var.disk_perm}"
    os_type           = "${var.ostype}"
    vhd_uri           = "https://myimages.blob.core.newone.net/myvhds/REDHAT7.vhd"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot create a VM from the VHD file in the different subscription. You 
 just can create the VM in the same subscription and same region with the VHD file. Not only the VM, but the image and snapshot are also the same limitations.

If you really want to create VM from the VHD file, you must copy the VHD file into the same subscription and region with anyway. I suggest the tool AzCopy.